# HTML Form text entry downloads file based on entry in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Need the form below to be able to download a pdf file based on the users entry.
If a user enters 1234 and hit enter key or download button, the 1234.pdf file gets downloaded.
If a user enters 12345, the 12345.pdf file gets downloaded.

```
<form action="">
<span class="text-red">Invalid Code</span>
<div class="input-group input-group-lg">
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="" required/>
<input  class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="DOWNLOAD" />
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your HTML code as per the following.

```
<form onsubmit="downloadURI()">
  <span class="text-red">Invalid Code</span>
  <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
      <input type="text" id="fileNumber" class="form-control" value="" onkeypress="OnEnterKyePress(event)" required/>
     <input  class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="DOWNLOAD" />
   </div>
</form>
```

And use the following JavaScript code. Here ../ means the root of the HTML file. ../Data means there is a Data folder at the root of the HTML file.

```
function OnEnterKyePress(e){
  if (e.keyCode == 13)
  {
      ldownloadURI();
  }
}
function downloadURI()
{
  var fileNumber=document.getElementById("fileNumber").value;  
  var fileUri="../data";
  downloadFile(fileUri, fileNumber+".pdf");
}

function downloadFile(uri, name) {
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.download = name;
  link.href = URI;
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link);
  delete link;
}
```

Comment: What if I'm pulling from a specific URL where we house the files?

Comment: @mark1178, then you should pass the URL value to "fileUri" variable.  And you should accept the answer if it meets your requirement for the future for anyone else.

Comment: I tried it out on my test page and it didn't work, 1234 and 12345 should have pulled the 1234.pdf and 12345.pdf but no dice. https://marktiongco.com/test/

Comment: @mark1178 , You've passed "link.href = URI", but is should be "link.href = uri;" inside the downloadFile function. Hope it'll work for you now. Happy coding.

Comment: Thank you that worked!

Comment: That's sounds good when it works.